# How to use a UDF with cell ranges in a worksheet?

Tags: arrays, excel, user-defined-functions, vba

I am trying to create a user defined function for use in an excel worksheet. My function uses three cell ranges as input and should return one single value as result. As such it is similar in structure to e.g. the SUMPRODUCT function, only the math that is performed is different.

This is the code I'm using:

```
Function MyFunction(C(), V(), M()) As Double
    Application.Volatile (True)

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, x As Long
    Dim Sum_Phi_i As Double

    x = UBound(C, 0)

    MyFunction = 0
    For i = 0 To x
        Sum_Phi_i = 0
        For j = 0 To x
        Sum_Phi_i = Sum_Phi_i + C(j) * Sqr(2) / (4 * Sqr(1 + M(i) / M(j))) * (1 + Sqr(V(i) / V(j)) * (M(j) / M(i)) ^ 0.25) ^ 2
            Next j
        MyFunction = MyFunction + C(i) * V(i) / Sum_Phi_i
        Next i

End Function
```

The problem I have with this is that it returns the #VALUE! error. Apparently I'm incorrectly defining data types since when I use this function in a worksheet I get:
[A value used in the formula is of the wrong data type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2bTB.jpg)

I have tried defining the used arrays C, M & V as Range or as Double to no avail. How can I solve this problem?

Besides this problem I'm also wondering how I can make sure that the cell ranges that are selected are of the same size. I was thinking of something in the way of:

```
x = UBound(C, 0)
y = UBound(M, 0)
z = UBound(M, 0)

If x <> y Or x <> z Or y <> z Then MyFunction = "Arrays are not of same size"
If x <> y Or x <> z Or y <> z Then Exit Function
```

Would this work? Or will this create problems since the output would be a string, whereas I defined my "MyFunction" as double? If so, how could that be solved or are there better ways to force the user to make same sized range selections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this function. It's tested, except for your formulas in which I have added parentheses, however, to separate the additions from the multiplications, like `Fun = Fun + (3 * 4)` instead of `Fun = Fun + 3 * 4`.

```
Function MyFunction(C As Range, _
                    V As Range, _
                    M As Range) As Double
    ' 21 Oct 2017

    Application.Volatile (True)

    Dim Fun As Double                       ' function return value
    Dim ArrC, ArrV, ArrM
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, x As Long
    Dim PhiSum As Double

    ArrC = C.Value
    ArrV = V.Value
    ArrM = M.Value
    x = UBound(ArrC, 2)

    If (UBound(ArrC) > 1) Or (UBound(ArrV) > 1) Or (UBound(ArrM) > 1) Then
        MsgBox "Please specify horizontal ranges each" & vbCr & _
               "comprising a single row only.", vbExclamation, "Invalid parameter"
        Exit Function
    End If

    If (UBound(ArrV, 2) <> x) Or (UBound(ArrM, 2) <> x) Then
        MsgBox "Specified ranges must be of equal size.", _
               vbCritical, "Invalid parameter"
        Exit Function
    End If    

    For i = 1 To x
        PhiSum = 0
        For j = 1 To x
            PhiSum = PhiSum + (ArrC(1, j) * Sqr(2) _
                            / (4 * Sqr(1 + ArrM(1, i)) _
                            / ArrM(1, j)) * (1 + Sqr(ArrV(1, i) _
                            / ArrV(1, j)) * (ArrM(1, j) _
                            / ArrM(1, i)) ^ 0.25) ^ 2)
        Next j
        Fun = Fun + (ArrC(1, i) * ArrV(1, i) / PhiSum)
    Next i
    MyFunction = Fun
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I now get an actual result (though not the right one; I need to re-check my formula).

Comment: I was still wondering if it is possible to force the function to only accept one dimensional horizontal cell ranges (rows).

Comment: I have modified the code to include a rejected of multiple row selections. In fact that isn't necessary, however, because the code only processes the first row. If your worksheet's construction permits it would be better to let the user select the first range and let the code find the others. This would be possible if the other two are in consecutive rows.

Comment: Thanks for the extra help. Actually the fact that the code only processes the first row of the selected ranges is one of the reasons I want to limit the selection to one row. Otherwise a user might assume that all rows would be processed while that is not the case. 

Alternatively, having the code process the entire selection row by row doesn’t really make sense since the input selections would logically always be one dimensional. 

With regard to having the code auto completing the selections to consecutive rows it really wouldn’t make sense to do that due to the layout of the worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

Compiled but not tested...

```
Function MyFunction(C As Range, V As Range, M As Range) As Double

    Application.Volatile True
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, x As Long
    Dim Sum_Phi_i As Double
    Dim vC, vV, vM
    vC = C.Value
    vV = V.Value
    vM = M.Value

    x = UBound(vC, 1) 'dimensions are 1 and 2 and lower bound of each=1

    MyFunction = 0
    For i = 1 To x
        Sum_Phi_i = 0
        For j = 1 To x
            Sum_Phi_i = Sum_Phi_i + vC(j) * Sqr(2) / (4 * Sqr(1 + vM(i) / vM(j))) * _
                        (1 + Sqr(vV(i) / vV(j)) * (vM(j) / vM(i)) ^ 0.25) ^ 2
        Next j
        MyFunction = MyFunction + (vC(i) * vV(i) / Sum_Phi_i)
    Next i

End Function
```